# Ruby BigDecimal rounding

Tags: ruby

I would like to round a BigDecimal to 2 decimal places, but when using the round method, it doesn't seem to double round:

```
BigDecimal.new('43382.0249').round(2).to_s('F').should == '43382.03'
```

But instead, I get output: 43382.02

I've also tried all the other rounding modes available, `ROUND_UP` seems to do the job, but it screws up other rounding scenarios, e.g. '670.1541' becomes '670.16' (incorrect) instead of '670.15' (correct)

Comment: How would .024 round to 0.03?

Comment: Actually the rounding it's giving you is correct for standard rounding. You seem to have two difefrent algorithms and a random selection of them

Comment: What you're doing is called "creative rounding".  If you're working on an accounting system this is also known as "fraud".

Answer (score 9):

**The correct answer:** What you're doing is called "creative rounding". If you're working on an accounting system this is also known as "fraud".  You should not "round" like this.

**The answer you're looking for:**

You can accomplish this with an algorithm that does the following:

```
x = the number of decimal places you would like to consider
y = the number of decimal placed you would like left when you are re done
while( x >= y )
    round your number to x places
    x = x-1
```

So in ruby:

```
my_num = 1.2349
x = 100
y = 2
x.downto y do |i|
    my_num = my_num.round i
end
puts my_num
```

This gives us 1.24 and if my_num were 1.2341 it would give us 1.23.

Use wisely, if that's even possible?

Comment: Ruby supports `BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_UP`; maybe we should also add a mode for `BigDecimal::ROUND_FOUR_NINTHS_UP`? (I'm kidding...)

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that the number in question should indeed round to .02 and not .03 -- I believe there is no actual problem here. .024 rounds to 0.02

Answer (score 0):

if you want 43382.0249 to be 42283.03 then add 0.001 first
if you want 670.1541 to be 670.16 then add 0.001 first

Round down / up < 0.005, you appear to want < 0.006.

NB if your numbers can be negative then it's -0.001

Have a play anyway, but as long as you are consistent the basic idea should work.